# Python / Pandas: Writing to file on Networked Drive (Windows)

Tags: python, pandas, pandas.excelwriter

I'm trying to write to a file on a networked drive. I'm not getting any errors but the file is not getting created. Any suggestions?

```
# Dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(rwb_list_departments,columns=['Owned By Team','Major Incident','Status','Priority','Incident ID','Owned By','Short Description','Requester Display Name','Created Date Time','Closed Date Time','Department','Duration','NumDur'])

# writing to local drive as csv works great
df.to_csv('rwb_itsm_processed_tickets.csv',index=False,encoding='utf-8')

# Now write file to networked drive as excel
data_folder = Path('W:/CDS Analytics/RWB')

# combine path and file
file_to_write = data_folder / 'rwb_itsm_processed_tickets.xlsx'

# Specify a writer
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('file_to_write', engine='xlsxwriter')

# Write your DataFrame to a file     
df.to_excel(writer,'report')

# Save the result
writer.save()
```

Comment: I wonder how you didn't et error in `file_to_write = data_folder / 'rwb_itsm_processed_tickets.xlsx'`

Comment: Honestly, no error is being produced.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I made it work for my Mac

```
# Now write file to networked drive as excel
data_folder ='/Users/myname/Desktop/'

# combine path and file
file_to_write = data_folder + '/rwb_itsm_processed_tickets.xlsx'
```

P.S: I was unable to access `rwb_list_departments` so I just took following sample dataframe `df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8]], columns=["A", "B"])` and the file was created together with the dataframe data. Rest everything was kept same as in your code. The error seems to be in the command `Path` and then the way you are defining `file_to_write`

Comment: I tried replacing the / with the + as you did in your example but it actually throws an error, doesn't like the +.

Answer (score 0):

```
import os

user = os.environ.get('USERNAME') 

Data_Folder = r'C:\\Users\\'+ user +'\\Desktop\\'

file = data_folder + 'rwb_itsm_processed_tickets.xlsx'
```

I dont know why but my double "\" arnt showing up in my reply but use the double back slashes instead of single \